# Creating an overlap matrix

Tags: r, matrix, social-networking, stata

I have a list of individuals, charities, and years. I am trying to find out how many times individual `i` overlaps with individual `j` in a given charity and year. I would like to make a square matrix for every year and have any given cell tell me the number of overlaps.

Example of Data:

```
Individual    Year    Charity
    1         2003       A
    2         2003       A
    2         2003       B
    2         2005       A
   ...        ...       ...
   17         2003       A
   17         2003       B
```

Wanted Result 2003 (for every year):

```
    Individual       Individual_1    Individual_2    ...       Individual_17
        1                 .               1                      1
        2                 1               .                      2
       ...               ...             ...                    ...
        17                1               2                      .
```

I have heard that R is best for network data, but right now using Stata, I created a variable for each individual and then I am running an `if statement` that looks in the `[_n+x]` cell for the individual in the given column and places a one. I was then going to aggregate these data. This seems to be working but is very time intensive and I am sure there could be an error.

```
qui forval j = 1/1750 { 
gen individual_`j'= 0
}

qui forval j = 1/1750 {
replace individual_`j' = 1 if individual[_n+`j'] == 1 & year == 2002 & charity == "A"
}

qui forval j = 1/1750 {
replace individual_`j' = 1 if individual[_n+`j'] == 1 & year == 2003 & charity == "A"
}

qui forval j = 1/1750 {
replace individual_`j' = 1 if individual[_n+`j'] == 1 & year == 2004 & charity == "A"
}

qui forval j = 1/1750 {
replace individual_`j' = 1 if individual[_n+`j'] == 1 & year == 2005 & charity == "A"
}
```

I would then sum over each charity. The data are too numerous for this brute force to work, hopefully there is an easier way.

I am open to doing this outside of Stata.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how many times an individual `i` overlaps with individual `j`"? Can you post a representative example of your initial data, how you want it to look like and a description of their link? (Are you missing individual braces or are those supposed to be nested loops?)

Comment: @RobertoFerrer That was a typo and I added the data and wanted result

Comment: Are you trying to construct a sociomatrix (or social graph) of individuals who are connected by charities for each year?

Comment: @GaryWeissman Yes, by year. If this can be one matrix that is great, but I assumed it had to be one per year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did something kind of similar. First add a column combining year and charity. Then convert the data frame into a list of charities per individual. I called your example of the data `x`

```
x$info <- paste(x$Year,x$Charity,sep="_")
All_Groups.list <- vector(length(unique(x$Individual)),mode="list")
names(All_Groups.list) <- as.character(unique(x$Individual))
for (i in 1:length(All_Groups.list)) {
  All_Groups.list[i] <- list(c(as.character(x[x$Individual == names(All_Groups.list)[i],4])))
}
Self.Cor.table <- sapply(All_Groups.list, function(x) {
  sapply(All_Groups.list,function(y){
length(x[x %in% y])
  })
})
```

The output is a correlation table where the numbers count the overlap in attended events

```
> Self.Cor.table
   1 2 17
1  1 1  1
2  1 3  2
17 1 2  2
```

This differs from your desired output by giving the number of events attended by each individual instead of a `.` which I think is important because each individual attends a different number of events.

If you want it per year subset the data frame by year and repeat for each subset.

Comment: Can you please explain what the first line is doing? The total number of events is a nice addition, thanks

Comment: That adds a column combining year and charity, it becomes column 4 which is then placed into the list and used to check overlap. If you do it by year you don't need that line and will need to change from column 4 to column 3 in the list making loop.

Comment: Great! Last thing, is it possible to do it by a time indicator and output a separate table for each, or do I have to feed it subset by subset

Comment: Also I loaded the dataset for only one year. I have the columns: Individual, Charity, and Year, removed the first line of your code and I receive an error `Error in unique(x$Individual) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: I called your example data x, I don't know what you called your data, but if you called it say `dat` then replace `x$Individual` with `dat$Individual` in both places where it appears

Comment: I renamed my data `x`, loaded just one time period of data (so I removed the first line of your code),  and unfortunately this is not working. I am assuming that `y` is suppose to be `charity` or no?

Comment: y is supposed to be y

Comment: Figured it out. Is it possible to export this table to a `.csv`?

Comment: look into write.table and write.csv type `?write.csv`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might want to consider benchmarking the following.  First, tabulate all triplets (entries will be 1 or 0 depending on whether an individual contributed to the charity in the year):

```
tbl <- table(dat$Individual, dat$Charity, dat$Year)
```

Now we want to loop through each Year (which is the third dimension of `tbl`) and for each pair of rows (individuals), calculate the number of shared 1's.  Achieved as follows:

```
res <- apply(tbl, 3, function(x) x %*% t(x))
dim(res) <- c(dim(tbl)[1], dim(tbl)[1], dim(tbl)[3])
```